# Error al extraer datos con WebBrowser por ID

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

En un aplicación `WinForms`, mi código extrae sin problemas los datos de una web con este código:

```
Elemento3.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Elemento1").InnerText
Elemento3.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Elemento2").InnerText
Elemento3.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Elemento3").InnerText
Elemento3.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Elemento4").InnerText
```

La página donde la extraigo a veces tiene hasta 4 IDs que capturo, sin embargo, la web a veces solo muestra 3 IDs, entonces al buscar mi aplicación el "Elemento4", no lo encuentra  y me tira este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al no encontrar los IDs simplemente lo ignore y deje vacío el textbox donde extrae el dato?

Answer (score 2):

`GetElementByID` retorna null cuando el elemento no esta presente:

> Returns the first object with the same ID attribute as the specified
>   value, or null if the id cannot be found.

[GetElementByID - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

El problema es que intentas acceder al `InnerText` de un elemento que es `null`, por eso obtienes `NullReferenceException`.

Lo mas sencillo (y una de las sugerencias que el IDE te proporciona) sería asignar el InnerText solo cuando el resultado de obtener `Elemento4` no es nulo.

```
HtmlElement elem4 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Elemento4")
 If (elem4 IsNot Nothing) Then         
  Elemento3.Text = elem4.InnerText
 End If
```